# Which is the appropriate term to refer to the paper with barcodes that you pay in your internet banking or physical bank?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, american-english, terminology

I have an issue with an online purchase in the Steam platform. Now I need to open a ticket to get my issue solved, but I do not know which is the correct term to refer to the payment method that I have chosen. The payment method consists in generation of a paper/document with a barcode that represents a sequence of numbers. To pay, you need to access your  internet banking or go to your physical bank and scan the barcode or digit the sequence of numbers that are represented by the barcode.
The document looks like this:[image: Sample of the referred document]

So, my question is:

Which is the appropriate term to refer to the paper with barcodes that you pay in your internet banking or physical bank?

P.A.: Terms that Google have returned:
- Bank Slip
- Banking billets
- Bank ticket

Comment: Receipt? Docket? Statement?

Comment: I've never made a payment this way; I'm not familiar with the type of document you describe.  Could it possibly be a *money order*?

Comment: @Dog Lover what's the difference between these terms?

Comment: i've never seen barcodes on anything banking-related.  closest thing i can think of is reading off the numbers on the bottom of a [check](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cheque#Parts_of_a_cheque), where it shows the account number, routing number, and check number.

Comment: I don't do it, but I think you can "prepay" for lots of things in the UK (bus/train fares, cinema tickets, etc.). You don't need to *print* the barcode - [the provider/seller scans the image shown on your mobile device.](http://www.gatwickexpress.com/en/tickets-and-fares/buying-tickets/mobile-ticketing/). Whether it's on paper or a screen, I'd say it's still just a ***barcode***, but if paper you could call that the *[barcode] **label***.

Comment: The question was edited to include the terms found on Google.

Comment: This is not a common means of payment in the US, but, based on your description, I would just say "barcode", or perhaps "barcode label" or "barcode slip".

Comment: Edited to put a image that represents the referred document.

Comment: It would help if you told us that in Brazilian Portuguese this documents are called "***Ficha de Compensaçäo***" (at least according to the label in the bottom right corner of your image). The standard translation of *ficha* and *compensation* in English are *bill* / *tab* and *compensation* / *payment* respectively. The trinomial "***online bill pay***" widespread in retail banks here in the US, but typically there is no physical or paper component.

Comment: @DanBron here in Brazil no one usually says "ficha de compensação" . The common term here is "boleto" . Which, as far as I know, don't have I direct translation.

Comment: @FabioSilva In Spanish, at least, in told *boleto* usually corresponds to *ticket* in English.

Answer (score 1):

An **invoice** - or **purchase order** or **bill** - may have a barcode and a sequence of numbers on it. The barcode system allows you to pay the amount due on the document at a bank where a barcode scanner identifies the payer and all the information concerning your purchase.

> From [wikipedia:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invoice)
>     a typical invoice contains
>
> - The word invoice (or Tax Invoice).
> - A unique reference number (in case of correspondence about the invoice)
> - Date of the invoice.
> - Credit terms.
> - Name and contact details of the seller
> - Tax or company registration details of seller (if relevant)
> - Name and contact details of the buyer
> - Date that the goods or service was sent or delivered
> - Purchase order number (or similar tracking numbers requested by the buyer to be mentioned on the invoice)
> - Description of the product(s)
> - Unit price(s) of the product(s) (if relevant)
> - Total amount charged (optionally with breakdown of taxes, if relevant)
> - Payment terms (including method of payment, date of payment, and details about charges for late payment)

Answer (score 0):

In America, the piece of paper that you include when putting cash or checks into your bank account is called a [Deposit Slip](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/d/deposit-slip.asp).

I'm not sure if this is the same kind of slip you're talking about, though. In America, our checks and deposit slips have the account and routing numbers printed in [MICR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_ink_character_recognition) code, not barcode.

Comment: True, true. But you can't enter the barcode of a deposit slip to send payment to a third party.

Comment: Our deposit slips don't even have a barcode. In the US, checks and deposit slips use MICR, not barcode. I was assuming that the piece of paper he's talking about in his country is analogous.

Comment: I really think he's talking about some kind of cashier's check or money order. But we don't have a perfect analog so we don't have a specialized term.

Answer (score 0):

Actually that payment method is a lot common here in Brazil and some internacional sale sites offers this kind of payment. I had this doubt about the apropriate name to designate that paper too and I guess the better term is "banking billet" or maybe "bank billet". Here we call this paper "Boleto Bancário".

I hope I have helped you and since now my apologies for any mistakes on the english discourse (I'm still learning and trying to improve).

Comment: Hi and welcome to ELU Stack Exchange. To make this a more helpful answer, you could provide a reference that shows the definition for your term, and/or some citations of originally English uses of the term. As of now it's not clear whether your answer is a direct translation from Portuguese that might not be meaningful in English, or a phrase that really is used in English.

Comment: Hi! Thank you
My contribution was more to reinforce the understanding of that payment method. I'm brazilian and I can state that this payment method is really common here and is exactly as described for the person who asked the question about it. 
But about the English uses and definition of the term that I've suggest I found searching at Google on site like this one: http://www.linguee.com.br/ingles-portugues/traducao/banking+billet.html

Comment: Besides, someone said here that the name in Portuguese for this payment method is "Ficha de Compensação" but it's wrong; the correct name is "Boleto Bancário".

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I couldn't find a direct translation in English. I think that the best way to translate this is:
"bank billing barcode invoice."

Comment: What would you call it in whatever language you are trying to translate from?